# How can I emit if only another stream has already emitted item and it is not consumed in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

My question looks like simple but please see below.

```
stream alphabet : ----------------------(A)----------------------------(B)-----
stream number   : ---(1)-----(2)------------------(3)----(4)----(5)----------(6)----
emission        :    true    true                false   true   true         false
```

- emit true if there was no alphabet item emission
- emit false there was alphabet item emission and it is not consumed yet
- emit true if last emitted alphabet item has been consumed

is there any good operator for it..?

Comment: There is no easy way to detect if a value has been consumed. How and what would consume that value?

Comment: @akarnokd  "false" will be emitted at (3) because there was NEW (A). then i would say (A) has been consumed

Comment: Again, how and what would consume that value? What is the original requirement you tried to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

If Alphabet (steamA) is a Hot Observable, I think this hackish take/skip based code can answer your problem:

```
Observable.merge(streamA, Observable.just("init"))
  .switchMap(a -> {
    if ("init".equals(a)) return streamN.map(n -> true);
    return Observable.merge(
     streamN.take(1).map(n -> false),
     streamN.skip(1).map(n -> true)
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what "alphabet item emission [...] is not consumed yet" means for you. For this, one needs to know or control the recipient of the alphabet. Also there is a second consumer for the boolean output so there is a correlation between two flows.

```java
Observable<String> alphabetFlow = ...

Observable<Integer> numberFlow = ...

AtomicBoolean consumed = new AtomicBoolean(true);

alphabetFlow
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .doOnNext(letter -> consumed.set(false))
    .doAfterNext(letter -> consumed.set(true))
    .subscribe(letter -> {
         System.out.println("I'm consuming" + letter));
         Thread.sleep(2000); // simulate processing
         System.out.println("I've consumed" + letter));
    });

numberFlow
    .map(number -> consumed.get())
    .subscribe(status -> System.out.println("Status: " + status));

Thread.sleep(100000); // in case you have this in main(String[] args)
```